# Openlayers - input a multiple overlay popups

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I created the overlay in Openlayers map based on the following example

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overlay.html

but the example shows only one point, whereas I need them a few.

I tried to base the javascript element on the class instead of id

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

and finally instead of

**HTML**

```
  <div style="display: none;">         
  <font class="overlay" id="bubble">S4 chamber issue</font>
  <div id="marker2" title="Marker2"></div>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
 var marker2 = new ol.Overlay({
  position: pos2,
  positioning: 'center-center',
  element: document.getElementById('marker2'),
  stopEvent: false,
  });
  map.addOverlay(marker2);


var bubble = new ol.Overlay({
position: pos2,
element: document.getElementById('bubble'),
});
map.addOverlay(bubble);
```

I've done sth like this

**HTML**

```
    <div style="display: none;">
    <font class="tekst">S4 chamber issue</font>
    <div class="marker2" title="Marker2"></div>
```

**JS**

```
   var marker2 = new ol.Overlay({
    position: pos2,
    positioning: 'center-center',
    element: document.getElementsByClassName('marker2'),
    stopEvent: false,
    });
    map.addOverlay(marker2);

     var bubble = new ol.Overlay({
     position: pos2,
     element: document.getElementsByClassName('tekst'),
     });
     map.addOverlay(bubble);
```

Everything is gone. It looks like that the method getElementsByClassName() is not working at all. Is there any way to put a few points instead of one or instead of repeating the JS and CSS code, based on the element id?

[image]

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an index collection of elements similar to an array. The elememt option must be a single element, for example `element: document.getElementsByClassName('tekst')[0]`

Comment: You are brilliant! It comes! Thank you! That's a pity, that W3schools didn't provide this element. Everything would be clear from the very beginning.